# How to be able to highlight only singe mat-list element at a time

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have dynamic `mat-list`:

```
          <mat-list *ngFor="let item of (items$ | async)">
            <mat-list-item>
              <mat-checkbox
                [value]="item.id"
                (change)="doStuff($event)"
              >
              </mat-checkbox
              ><a (click)="getDetails(item.id)">{{
                item.title
              }}</a></mat-list-item
            >
          </mat-list>
```

on `getDetails` I am displaying some additional info in the `div` about the item and at the same time I want to highlight that particular selected item. Then if I click  other item I want only that one to be highlighted now and the other one to get unhighlighted.

I think I need to have a css class that just gets assigned on item being clicked but having difficulties to approach that in my particular use case.

How would you achieve that with a minimum pain? Any ideas?

UPDATE:
Currently playing with `@ViewChildren('#matList') myItems: ElementRef;` but no luck yet

Comment: just use a variable "selectedId", change in getDetails(item.id) and use [ngClass]="{'yourclass':item.id==selectedId}" (or [style.background-color]="item.id==selectedId?'Red':inherit"

Comment: @Eliseo yeah that is good idea and no need to deal with `@View*` directives. Exactly what I was looking for. Just place that as an answer and I will just accept that.